# A booktabs question: How to get rid of the blank column?

Tags: tabularx, booktabs

I tried to make a table like this: 
[image]

But I don't want those black space, how can I get ride of them? (I still want the table to have text width )

I referred to the latex code of 
http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf and [Help with a booktabs table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163061/help-with-a-booktabs-table)

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set margins to meet your document's needs
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Minimum Requirements for Automatic Readmission 
  into the Commerce Faculty} \label{table:mr}
%\centering  % not needed, since table is as wide as text block
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{rrcrrc}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries BCom}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries B.Bus Sci} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} 
\cmidrule(lr){4-5} 
& $N$ & $\%$ & $N$ & $\%$ 
\\\midrule
$dir=Dels$\\
$c$ & 0.0790 & 0.1692 & 0.2945 & 0.3670 \\
$c$ & -0.8651& 50.0476& 5.9384 & -9.0714& \\
$c$ & 124.2756& -50.9612& -14.2721& 128.2265&\\
$dir=0$\\
$c$ & 0.0357& 1.2473& 0.2119& 0.3593& \\
$c$ & -17.9048& -37.1111& 8.8591& -30.7381& \\
$c$ & 105.5518& 232.1160& -94.7351& 100.2497&\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest thing to do is to change the `tabularx` into a `tabular*` and manually set `\tabcolsep` to some appropriate value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set margins to meet your document's needs
%\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\hspace{\fil}\raggedright\arraybackslash}X} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Minimum Requirements for Automatic Readmission 
  into the Commerce Faculty} \label{table:mr}
%\centering  % not needed, since table is as wide as text block
\tabcolsep=27.8pt\relax
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{rrcrrc}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries BCom}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries B.Bus Sci} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} 
\cmidrule(lr){4-5} 
& $N$ & $\%$ & $N$ & $\%$ 
\\\midrule
$dir=Dels$\\
$c$ & 0.0790 & 0.1692 & 0.2945 & 0.3670 \\
$c$ & -0.8651& 50.0476& 5.9384 & -9.0714& \\
$c$ & 124.2756& -50.9612& -14.2721& 128.2265&\\
$dir=0$\\
$c$ & 0.0357& 1.2473& 0.2119& 0.3593& \\
$c$ & -17.9048& -37.1111& 8.8591& -30.7381& \\
$c$ & 105.5518& 232.1160& -94.7351& 100.2497&\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want a table with a width of text width. You could have used the regular `tabular` instead of `tabularx`. However, needs are needs and somebody  else will decide them. Hence here is an option. Use `tabulary` instead of `tabularx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabulary}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set margins to meet your document's needs
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Minimum Requirements for Automatic Readmission
  into the Commerce Faculty} \label{table:mr}
%\centering  % not needed, since table is as wide as text block
\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{rrcrrc}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries BCom}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries B.Bus Sci} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
& $N$ & $\%$ & $N$ & $\%$
\\\midrule
$dir=Dels$\\
$c$ & 0.0790 & 0.1692 & 0.2945 & 0.3670 \\
$c$ & -0.8651& 50.0476& 5.9384 & -9.0714& \\
$c$ & 124.2756& -50.9612& -14.2721& 128.2265&\\
$dir=0$\\
$c$ & 0.0357& 1.2473& 0.2119& 0.3593& \\
$c$ & -17.9048& -37.1111& 8.8591& -30.7381& \\
$c$ & 105.5518& 232.1160& -94.7351& 100.2497&\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}

With just \verb|tabular|:

\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Minimum Requirements for Automatic Readmission
  into the Commerce Faculty} \label{table:mr}
%\centering  % not needed, since table is as wide as text block
\begin{tabular}{rrcrrc}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries BCom}
&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries B.Bus Sci} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
& $N$ & $\%$ & $N$ & $\%$
\\\midrule
$dir=Dels$\\
$c$ & 0.0790 & 0.1692 & 0.2945 & 0.3670 \\
$c$ & -0.8651& 50.0476& 5.9384 & -9.0714& \\
$c$ & 124.2756& -50.9612& -14.2721& 128.2265&\\
$dir=0$\\
$c$ & 0.0357& 1.2473& 0.2119& 0.3593& \\
$c$ & -17.9048& -37.1111& 8.8591& -30.7381& \\
$c$ & 105.5518& 232.1160& -94.7351& 100.2497&\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or I might have just misunderstood the question (after seeing Steven's answer). You can define new columns like

```
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
```

Also, you are using 5 columns entries but declaring 6 columns. Remove them like the following (i.e., just 5 columns).

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YYZYY}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set margins to meet your document's needs
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Minimum Requirements for Automatic Readmission
  into the Commerce Faculty} \label{table:mr}
%\centering  % not needed, since table is as wide as text block
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{YYZYY}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}Z}{\bfseries BCom}
&\multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}Z}{\bfseries B.Bus Sci} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
& $N$ & $\%$ & $N$ & $\%$
\\\midrule
$dir=Dels$\\
$c$ & 0.0790 & 0.1692 & 0.2945 & 0.3670 \\
$c$ & -0.8651& 50.0476& 5.9384 & -9.0714 \\
$c$ & 124.2756& -50.9612& -14.2721& 128.2265\\
$dir=0$\\
$c$ & 0.0357& 1.2473& 0.2119& 0.3593 \\
$c$ & -17.9048& -37.1111& 8.8591& -30.7381 \\
$c$ & 105.5518& 232.1160& -94.7351& 100.2497\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]